# convert python function to pyspark lambda function

Tags: python, dataframe, lambda, pyspark

I have a python function like below

```
def func(a, b, c):
    if c != 0:
        return b/c * a
    else:
        return a
```

I wanted to create a lambda function for this I have tried creating a lambda function like below

```
 func = lambda x,y,z : y/z * x if z != 0 else z
```

but getting error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

This is how I am calling

```
df= df.withColumn('new_col' ,func('x', 'y', 'z'))
```

Even I tried casting columns to float but still getting an issue.

Note: I do not want it to be created a UDF because I am working with a huge dataset and UDFs are taking a lot of time so looking for a Lambda function

Answer (score 1):

You are calling your `lambda` function wrong.

You pass it 3 string rather then numeric variables, you should pass the values of `x`/`y`/`z` rather then calling the the strings. You should probably do the following:

```
df= df.withColumn('new_col' ,func($'x', $'y', $'z'))
# Or
df= df.withColumn('new_col' ,func(df['x'], df['y'], df['z']))
```

But I can't be sure without you sharing the data-frame structure.

Pay closer attention to the error messages. It clearly states that the variable you passed to the function are strings and you can't perform an arithmetic operation on strings.